# Spring Bean Validation with configurable constraint values

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I'd like to make Java Bean Validation constraints configurable by Spring, possibly by using properties. An example:

```
class Pizza {

    @MaxGramsOfCheese(max = "${application.pizza.cheese.max-grams}")
    int gramsOfCheese;

}
```

I haven't been able to get this to work or find much documentation about this.

Is something like this even possible? I know that messages are configurable in a Validationmessages.properties file, so I'm hoping something similar is possible for constraint values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Madhu Bhat you can configure your `ConstraintValidator` class to read properties from Spring's `Environment`.

```java
public class MaxGramsOfCheeseValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxGramsOfCheese, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private int max;

    public void initialize(MaxGramsOfCheese constraintAnnotation) {
        this.max = Integer.valueOf(env.resolvePlaceholders(constraintAnnotation.max()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && value <= this.max;
    }

}
```

Thus you can use `@MaxGramsOfCheese` annotation on different fields with different parameters which may be more appropriate in your case.

```java
class Pizza {

    @MaxGramsOfCheese(max = "${application.pizza.cheddar.max-grams}")
    int gramsOfCheddar;

    @MaxGramsOfCheese(max = "${application.pizza.mozerella.max-grams}")
    int gramsOfMozerella;

}
```

Comment: I like this solution, because it keeps max configurable either with a property or with a fixed value (although this needs to be programmed). Unfortunately this doesn't work: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${application.pizza.cheddar.max-grams}"`.

Comment: It is probably caused by you do not have the property definition in your `application.properties` file. You can simply define a default value like `${application.pizza.cheddar.max-grams:5}`. In addition, you can change the method `env.resolvePlaceholders` to `env.resolveRequiredPlaceholders` in the `MaxGramsOfCheeseValidator`. This will force to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when there is no property found with the key you add to the annotation. Thus you can handle this scenario as you need or just log for a warning.

Comment: I had the property defined in an application.yml. Seems these are not read correctly. When changing to an application.properties it works.

Comment: Glad it works :) It is strange normally it should work. If you have both `.properties` and `.yml` then for the same keys `.properties` file overrides the `.yml` one. Maybe that is the case but I'm not sure.

Comment: What about if I use my own properties file, like myprops.properties? This file is also in resource folder, how to access it via Environment? Or is another solution necessary?

Comment: As I know only the `application-{profile}.properties` files imported automatically. The others like as you said for `myprops.properties` you need to import it manually to your Spring's configuration file. Ex: `@PropertySource("classpath:myprops.properties")`

Comment: Then, you can access these properties by using Spring's `Environment` as I guess.

Answer (score 3):

For any custom validation, you need to implement a **custom validator** by implementing the `ConstraintValidator` interface, and then provide that custom validator to the custom validation annotation that you create.

**The custom validator:**

```
public class MaxGramsOfCheeseValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxGramsOfCheese, Integer> {

    @Value("${application.pizza.cheese.max-grams}")
    protected int maxValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MaxGramsOfCheese constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && value <= maxValue;
    }

}
```

**The custom validation annotation:**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MaxGramsOfCheeseValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MaxGramsOfCheese {
    String message() default "Some issue here"; //message to be returned on validation failure

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Using the custom validation annotation:**

```
class Pizza {

    @MaxGramsOfCheese
    int gramsOfCheese;

}
```

Note that if you want the value for the annotation to be accessed from the properties file, you'll have to provide that in the custom validator as shown.