# Spring Boot - Constraint Validator @Autowired field null

Tags: java, spring-boot

`@Autowired` not working, `Environment env` is always null.

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Override
  public void initialize(MyConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
     env.resolvePlaceholders(...));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String string, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Otherwise if use a constructor with parameter `Environment` and assign it to local `Environment env`, with `@Autowired` on the constructor, it is not null. But then the `initialize(...)` method is not called.

What is the solution?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read the question good enough. You cannot use @Autowired. You have to create a constructor with an Enviroment as Parameter.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Why can't they use `@Autowired`?

Comment: Hmm. With older Spring versions that didn't work but now I see that this should be possible: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation

Comment: If I use a constructor, somehow the initialize method is not called. I use Spring Boot 2.2.6 and JDK 14

Comment: Please provide the relevant code as requested previously.

Comment: Provide the code in your question, not in an answer. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

MyConstraintValidator  is not a Bean (ex. @Service, @Component) it can't Autowire other beans.
If you need to access some properties from environment, there's a way to put them to static context through implementing EnvironmentAware

[Spring Boot - Environment @Autowired throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454289/spring-boot-environment-autowired-throws-nullpointerexception)

Comment: It might be a bean through `@Bean`? It doesn't have to be annotated with `@Component`. Also, how do you explain their claim that it works when they use a constructor?

Comment: @Savior, looks like spring raises beans for all ConstraintValidator classes via ConstraintValidatorFactory. Just checked a sample with Autowired as in the question above, worked without any issues

Comment: @neblaz, could you share MyConstraint class? I faced, that initialize block was not called unless MyConstraint  contained groups & payload methods.

Comment: It is basically this example (marked as correct): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920934/spring-bean-validation-with-configurable-constraint-values

Answer (score -1):

I can't use comments, but you can try referencing this [answer about Spring Inversion of Control Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null).

It looks like Spring doesn't know about your class, so it doesn't know to auto-inject Environment. You can try annotating it with Spring's `@Component` and see if that helps.