# Validate POJOs using application.yaml values

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, yaml

I want to use some validation for this POJO:

```
@Data
public class Simulation {

  ...

  @DecimalMin(value = "${minimum-value}")
  private BigDecimal value;
  
  ...

}
```

Using this YAML configuration:

```
minimum-value: 500
```

It seems I'm missing something, because I get the following error whenever an instance of `Simulation` is created:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HV000016: ${minimum-value} does not represent a valid BigDecimal format.
```

Comment: I think your question is answered here: [Spring Bean Validation with configurable constraint values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920934/spring-bean-validation-with-configurable-constraint-values)

Comment: Interesting. But I have to create my own `DecimalMin` version then, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should define your own annotation with the required parameter(s). See how `@MaxGramsOfCheese` is implemented in the answers.